# Caml Query weekly and monthly

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, sharepoint-list

[image]I want to build a CAML query that show the data on  monthly and weekly basis. 
Please help me to provide the best solutions for the query

In SharePoint there is a list created for leave application that is having five column Name,type of leave , details , start date and end date . I want to fetch the data from the list that will show weekly employees onleave and monthly employees on leave

above is my list image

Now from this i have the html page to display the data from above list
Now please provide me the query that i add in my javscript on where condition is check for month and week to display in my html page using script

Comment: and which column should be used for the filtering for the month and week? Created? Provide us more information please.

Comment: hi i made the changes as you requested to do so

Comment: Thanks, so you want to do : Montly > StartDate(1st of ThisMonth) - EndDate(Last of ThisMonth) and Weekly > StartDate(Monday this Week) - EndDate(Sunday this Week) query in caml, right?

Comment: and where you want to use it, in c# application for SharePoint or in any view on SharePoint?

Comment: i want to use it on sharepoint view

Comment: Ok, i will test it and send a solution

Answer (score 2):

OK it take me a while, but here is the solution:
You need to create 2 calculated columns for Month filtering and 2 calculated columns for Week filtering. View with filtering for each.

*EndDate in the formulas is the EndDate internal name of the our colum "end date". 
Replace ; with , depends on environment localization.*

**Month Filtering**

Create Calculated columns:

- StartMonth - formula: `=DATE(YEAR(EndDate);MONTH(EndDate);1)` outcome: DateTime, Date only
- EndMonth - formula `=DATE(YEAR(EndDate);MONTH(EndDate)+1;1)-1` outcome: DateTime, Date only

Create view with filter:

MonthLeaving - filter:

[image]

**Week filtering**

Create Calculated columns:

- StartOfWeek - formula: `=EndDate-WEEKDAY(EndDate)+1` outcome: DateTime, Date only
- EndOfWeek - formula: `=StartOfWeek+6` outcome: DateTime, Date only

Create view with filter:

WeekLeaving - filter:

[image]

**How it looks like:**

[image: All users]

[image: Monthly leaving]

[image: Weekly leaving]

*It worked well for me. Hope you like it!*

**CAML Queries instead of SharePoint Views:** Replace (Today) with date in format YYYY-MM-dd.

Monthly Leave:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='StartMonth' />
            <Value Type='Calculated'>(Today)</Value>
         </Leq>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EndMonth' />
            <Value Type='Calculated'>(Today)</Value>
         </Geq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Weekly Leave:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='StartOfWeek' />
            <Value Type='Calculated'>(Today)</Value>
         </Leq>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='EndOfWeek' />
            <Value Type='Calculated'>(Today)</Value>
         </Geq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: I updated my question with image please review than reply over it if you need any more information

Comment: but i asked you and you wrote you want it in sharepoint view... so please make this as answer and create new topic about the caml query and i will add it tomorrow.

Comment: Where you want to use this Page? It will be on SharePoint or somewhere else?

Comment: i will using this list in sharepoint designer with i create a text file there i have script with me but how i  will use this list in that script with the help of caml query

Comment: I added these queries. Post edited.

Comment: ok I will try this solution

Comment: Did you help my answer? Mark it please.